# Create a new select dropdown object with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a select (`<select><option...</select>`) object in jQuery.

I [tried this](https://jsfiddle.net/12xfuz4j/), but it won't add the option values and text:

```
var photos = [
    '_DSC0153.jpg',
    '_DSC0154.jpg'
];

var dropdown = $("<select>", {
    id: 'selectfile'
    , option: { value: '0', text: photos[0] }
    , option: { value: '1', text: photos[1] }
});
dropdown.appendTo( $('#gallery') );
```

[This other version (dynamic)](https://jsfiddle.net/c3kyxtud/1/) won't even show the select element:

```
var photos = [
    '_DSC0153.jpg',
    '_DSC0154.jpg'
];

var dropdown = $("<select>", {
    id: 'selectfile',
    for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        option: { value: i, text: photos[i] }
    }
});
dropdown.appendTo( $('#gallery') );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

```
var photos = [
    '_DSC0153.jpg',
    '_DSC0154.jpg'
];

// creating the <select> element:
$('<select>', {
    // setting its 'id' property/attribute:
    'id' : 'selectfile'
// in order to append nodes (rather than a string of HTML),
// we use the append() method:
}).append(function () {
    // using Array.prototype.map() to iterate
    // over the given (photos) array, creating a
    // a new array. Using the anonymous function's
    // arguments (el: the array-element itself,
    // i: the index of the array-element) to
    // create new <option> elements using the
    // new Option() Constructor; setting
    // its text (to the filename, el) and
    // value (to the index, i):
    return photos.map(function(el,i){
        return new Option(el, i);
    });
// appending the <select> to the <body>:
}).appendTo('body');
```

```js
var photos = [
  '_DSC0153.jpg',
  '_DSC0154.jpg'
];

$('<select>', {
  'id': 'selectfile'
}).append(function() {
  return photos.map(function(el, i) {
    return new Option(el, i);
  });
}).appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ejuckzd4/), for experimentation.

If, however, you would prefer to set a string of HTML in the `<select>`-creation stage, that's entirely possible:

```
var photos = [
  '_DSC0153.jpg',
  '_DSC0154.jpg'
];

$('<select>', {
  'id': 'selectfile',

  // using Array.prototype.map() again,
  // iterating over the photos array, creating
  // a new array:
  'html': photos.map(function(el, i) {

    // creating new <option> elements (as above)
    // setting text and values (as before); but
    // but this time we return the 'outerHTML'
    // property of the created <option> element,
    // creating an array of HTML:
    return new Option(el, i).outerHTML;

  // joining the array of HTML together with empty strings:
  }).join('')
}).appendTo('body');
```

```js
var photos = [
  '_DSC0153.jpg',
  '_DSC0154.jpg'
];

$('<select>', {
  'id': 'selectfile',
  'html': photos.map(function(el, i) {
    return new Option(el, i).outerHTML;
  }).join('')
}).appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ejuckzd4/1), for experimentation.

In the above code the use of `join('')` is not necessary ([JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ejuckzd4/2/)) but, as a matter of personal preference – and habit, I tend to use it regardless.

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML).
  - [`Option()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option).
- jQuery:

  - [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
  - [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
var photos = ['_DSC0153.jpg', '_DSC0154.jpg'];
var dropdown = $("<select>", {
    id: 'selectfile'
});

//Iterate the photos 
//Create option 
//and append it to select
for (i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
    var option = $('<option></option>', {
        value: i,
        text: photos[i]
    });
    dropdown.append(option);
}
dropdown.appendTo('#gallery');
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/m2cxL4xq/)